# No puedo vincular odoo web en un contenedor con la db alojada en otro contenedor

Tags: postgresql, odoo, enlace, contenedores

Mi maquina que almacenaba odoo se apago y tras reanudarla arranco los dos dockers pero me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

creo que se ha desligado mi docker web con mi db del otro docker, hago un `docker network ls` para ver las redes de este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad es que no se como seguir a partir de aquí ya que estoy aprendiendo con docker y no se como vincular un container con el otro, mis docker son los siguientes:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
fb7a45642fff        odoo                "/entrypoint.sh odoo"    27 minutes ago      Created                                                extra-addons_odoo1
beafcb94792b        odoo:11             "/entrypoint.sh odoo"    10 months ago       Up 13 minutes       0.0.0.0:8069->8069/tcp, 8071/tcp   extra-addons_odoo_1
949c8293fe95        postgres:9.4        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 months ago       Up 39 minutes       0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp             extra-addons_db_1
```

He encontrado dicho codigo que quizas sea de mi utilidad, pero sigue sin funcionarme:

```
docker run -p 0.0.0.0:8069:8069 --name extra-addons_odoo1 --link extra-addons_db_1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Usa enlace de contenedores**

Los contenedores pueden vincularse a los puertos de otros contenedores directamente utilizando el siguiente parámetro al ejecutar el docker cliente:

```
-link remote_name:local_alias
```

Este establece una serie de variables de entorno que luego se pueden usar para conectarte:

```
$ docker run --rm -t -i --link pg_test:pg eg_postgresql bash

$ psql -h $PG_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR -p $PG_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT -d docker
```

**FUENTE EN SITIO DE DOCKER**

https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/postgresql_service/